# Downloading is working fine in desktop browser but not in mobile browsers

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET, specially web based application. I have written a webpage for downloading the image from server. It works fine when I try to download from desktop browser, but it does not download if I try to download from iPad or Android tablets. In iPad It shows some encoded string while in case of Android, it downloads an HTML file of the same page. My code is as below :

```
string file = obj.Base_Url; // NAME OF THE FILE ON THE SERVER e.g; A.png
string imageUrl = Server.MapPath("~/Images" + '/' + file);
Response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownloadToken", download_token_value.Value));
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images" + '/' + file));
Response.Flush();
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; (or png/gif...) before the Response.WriteFile line.